# Trying to set package.json for MERN app in Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, build

I am a bit new to this area and I I am missing something fundamental.  I have a very basic shell of an application:

Client path:  src/index.js

Server path:  server/index.js

Procfile:  web:node server/index.js

root package.json:

```
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
```

How do I tell heroku where the client files are?  Do I need a "start" script in the root's package.json?  From the examples that I've seen they usually had "node " to start the express server.  Do I need to set up something like webpack for the client server?

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore.  I have done this in the past and got myself turned around by looking through various guides.  It was a comedy of errors, starting with mistakenly having type:module in the package.json (I had created it elsewhere originally) and that put me down a rabbit hole of making the wrong decisions.